# What is the masculine equivalent for a bus matron?

Tags: nouns

Is there a masculine equivalent for matron (as a bus matron)?

Comment: A *Bus Matron* is a "Protective Service Worker". If the slot is filled by a *male*, he could just use that more generic term, or identify himself as a [Bus Escort, Monitor, Steward, Security Officer, Ranger, Marshal](http://www.mymajors.com/career/bus-matron/) depending on how strongly he (or his employers) want to allude to *[military] **authority***.

Comment: Joan, please provide us with the definition of Bus Matron that you are using.

Comment: I think many of us have never heard the term -- a definition would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**Bus Escort** seems to be the most common from news articles, application forms, Craigslist, etc. Though every link I've found looks to ephemeral to embed.

Not particularly masculine, but at least neutral I would have thought.

Comment: If anyone can find anything reasonably long-lived-looking on the web, I'll happily add it as a link.

Answer (score 2):

*[Bus steward](http://occupations.careers.org/17252/bus-steward)* seems equivalent. From occupations.careers.org:

> **Career Occupational Profile for Bus Steward**
>
> Bus Steward is very similar to another occupation for which we have a
>   full profile. Check out our full profile for:
>   *Transportation Attendants*
>
> **Overview**
>
> Provide services to ensure the safety and comfort of passengers aboard
>   ships, buses, trains, or within the station or terminal. Perform
>   duties, such as greeting passengers, explaining the use of safety
>   equipment, serving meals or beverages, or answering questions related
>   to travel.
>
> ---
>
> *[Transportation Attendants](http://occupations.careers.org/39-6032.00/transportation-attendants)*
>
> **Occupation Profile for Transportation Attendants**
>
> Provide services to ensure the safety and comfort of passengers aboard
>   ships, buses, trains, or within the station or terminal. Perform
>   duties, such as greeting passengers, explaining the use of safety
>   equipment, serving meals or beverages, or answering questions related
>   to travel.

Comment: I looked at occupations.careers.org but it appears to be quite trashy. It's overview for a Bus Matron suggested that they "Attend to children at schools, businesses, private households, and child care institutions. Perform a variety of tasks, such as dressing, feeding, bathing, and overseeing play." which sound more like a generic child care worker which has been pasted into any job vaguely related to kids.

Comment: @DanSheppard So does the *Bus* refer to transport, or to some sort of availability criteria, like *bank nurse*? "Bus matron" is something I've never heard of in the UK; *matron* suggests child-care; but *bus* suggests a bus conductress.

Comment: As I understand it (I'm also UK based) a bus matron is someone who keeps order on a school bus and hurries children onto and off the bus.